# How do I get these buttons to show centered in a line?

Tags: html, css

If at all possible what I'd like to do is split the page into 3 sections and and have each button take up an entire section so its easy to click.

I have these set up how I thought it would work displaying the buttons like so:

```
Last

Next

Stop
```

What I end up with is completely wrong for some reason. It displays Last and Stop on the bottom over the page ontop of one another.

Code:

```css
@keyframes hue {
  0% {
    filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

.canvas-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#freq {
    background: linear-gradient(#ff0088, red);
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
body {
    background:#000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#freq.animateHue, body.animateHue {
    animation-name: hue;
    animation-duration: 500s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    -webkit-animation-name: hue;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 500s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#title, #artist, #album {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    /*font-size: 100px;*/
    color: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    letter-spacing: -.05em;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#song_info_wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center; 
}

#title {
 font-size: 10vw;
}

#artist {
    font-size: 3vw;
}
#album {
    font-size: 3vw;
 /*font-size: 40px;*/
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

input, #loading {
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 left: 40%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
    
}

#songName {
 position: absolute;
 top: 80%;
 right: 19%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    /*font-size: 100px;*/
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: -.05em;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(20, 20, 20, 20);
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 font-size: 3vw;
}

#c1, #c2 {
    width: 33%;
}

#c3 {
    width: auto;
}

#playSampleButton {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-size: 13vw;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: -.05em;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin: auto;
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
}
#buttonSmall {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-size: 10vw;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    letter-spacing: -.05em;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
}

#buttonStop {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-size: 10vw;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    letter-spacing: -.05em;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
}



#loading {
 display: inline-block;
 top: 44px; 
 left: 110px;
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif; 
 font-size: 12px;
}

html, body {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
 #title {
  font-size: 100px;
 }

 #artist, #album {
  font-size: 40px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 #artist, #album {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 4vw;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 436px) {
 #artist, #album {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 4.5vw;
 }
 
 #title {
  
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content='IE=8' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
        <title>Frequcency analysis using HTML5 Audio and Web Audio API</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <!-- Das favicon.ico und das apple-touch-icon.png in das root Verzeichnis -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="src/bufferloader.js"></script>
        <script src="src/id3-minimized.js"></script>
        <script src="src/audiovisualisierung.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
  <p class="songName" id="songName"></p>
        <span id="loading"></span>
        <div id="song_info_wrapper">
  </div>
        <div class="canvas-container">
            <canvas id="freq" width="1024" height="525"></canvas>
            <div id="c3">
                <button id="playSampleButton" type="button" onClick="playNext()">Next</button>
            </div>
            <div id="c1">
                <button id="buttonSmall" type="button" onClick="playLast()">Last</button>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div id="c2">
                <button id="buttonStop" type="button" onClick="playStop()">Stop</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked into flexbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your button heights and the heights of the divs they are in. First, you have not given the c1/c2/c3 containers a height, so setting the button height to 100% will not work - they are 100% of undefined.

Below, I did not completely solve this for you, but I did over-ride the heights for these elements and you can see the difference (you'll need to look at the demo "Full Page" *(link at top-right)* to see it...).

```css
#c1, #c2, #c3{height:30vh !important;}
#playSampleButton,
#buttonSmall,
#buttonStop{height:20vh !important;}


html, body{width: 100%;height:100%;margin:0px;}
.canvas-container{position:relative;width:100%;height:100vh;}
#freq{background:linear-gradient(#ff0088, red);position:absolute;left:0;right:0;margin:0 auto;}
body{background:#000;overflow:hidden;}
#freq.animateHue, body.animateHue{animation-name:hue;animation-duration:500s;animation-delay:1s;animation-iteration-count:infinite;-webkit-animation-name:hue;-webkit-animation-duration:500s;-webkit-animation-delay:1s;-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;}
#title, #artist, #album{position:relative;text-align:center;width:100%;z-index:999;font-weight:100;font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;font-size:100px;color:#fff;visibility:hidden;letter-spacing:-.05em;text-shadow:0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);margin-bottom:15px;}
#song_info_wrapper{position:absolute;width:100%;text-align:center;}
#title{font-size:10vw;}
#artist{font-size:3vw;}
#album{font-size:3vw;font-size:40px;margin-bottom:0;}

input, #loading{position:absolute;top:45%;left:40%;display:block;z-index:999;}
#songName{position:absolute;top:80%;right:19%;display:block;z-index:999;width:100%;font-weight:100;font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;font-size:100px;color:#fff;letter-spacing:-.05em;text-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(20, 20, 20, 20);margin-bottom:15px;font-size:3vw;}
#c1, #c2{width:33%;}
#c3{width:auto;}
#playSampleButton{padding:10px 25px;font-size:13vw;height:100%;width:100%;color:#fff;font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;z-index:999;position:relative;letter-spacing:-.05em;text-shadow:0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);margin:auto;background-color:Transparent;background-repeat:no-repeat;border:none;cursor:pointer;overflow:hidden;outline:none;}
#buttonSmall{padding:10px 25px;font-size:10vw;height:100%;width:100%;color:#fff;font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;z-index:999;position:absolute;letter-spacing:-.05em;text-shadow:0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);background-color:Transparent;background-repeat:no-repeat;border:none;cursor:pointer;overflow:hidden;outline:none;}
#buttonStop{padding:10px 25px;font-size:10vw;height:100%;width:100%;color:#fff;font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;z-index:999;position:absolute;letter-spacing:-.05em;text-shadow:0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);background-color:Transparent;background-repeat:no-repeat;border:none;cursor:pointer;overflow:hidden;outline:none;}

#loading{display:inline-block;top:44px;left:110px;font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;font-size:12px;}

@keyframes hue{
    0%{filter:hue-rotate(0deg);-webkit-filter:hue-rotate(0deg);}
  100%{filter:hue-rotate(-360deg);-webkit-filter:hue-rotate(-360deg);}
}

@media screen and (min-width:1000px){
    #title{font-size:100px;}
 #artist, #album{font-size:40px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px){
    #artist, #album{font-weight:300;font-size:4vw;}
}

@media screen and (max-width:436px){
    #artist, #album{font-weight:300;font-size:4.5vw;}
 #title{}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content='IE=8' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
        <title>Frequcency analysis using HTML5 Audio and Web Audio API</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <!-- Das favicon.ico und das apple-touch-icon.png in das root Verzeichnis -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="src/bufferloader.js"></script>
        <script src="src/id3-minimized.js"></script>
        <script src="src/audiovisualisierung.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
  <p class="songName" id="songName"></p>
        <span id="loading"></span>
        <div id="song_info_wrapper">
  </div>
        <div class="canvas-container">
            <canvas id="freq" width="1024" height="525"></canvas>
            <div id="c3">
                <button id="playSampleButton" type="button" onClick="playNext()">Next</button>
            </div>
            <div id="c1">
                <button id="buttonSmall" type="button" onClick="playLast()">Last</button>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div id="c2">
                <button id="buttonStop" type="button" onClick="playStop()">Stop</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```